# Facebook debugger not working with Angular NG SERVE in DEV environment

Tags: angular, facebook, facebook-like

I am building a website using Angular CLI 9.1 using CentOS 7.

I have a domain `a.com` registered (for PROD environment), and `dev.a.com` (for DEV environment).

I also had correctly configured the DNS, so `a.com` points to my production server, and `dev.a.com` points to my home dev machine.

I had correctly configured the SSL certificates for each domain. None of the online tools I used such as [SSL Shoper](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html) (and many others) see any problem with my certificates. I am not using the same certificate in both cases, but a different one for each domain. The first certificate will match `*.a.com`, and the second will match `*.dev.a.com`.

The DEV environment is correctly configured to accept external connections. For example, I can load the DEV version of the website in my phone after disabling the WIFI and using only 4G connection. And this is true, either using the DEV-DIST version (served by Apache as a regular website, port 80) or the Angular built in server (`ng serve`, using port 4202)

The [Facebook Sharer debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) also gives me the expected results, either with the PROD version or the DEV-DIST version of the website. URLS such as `https://a.com/some/other/page` and `https://dev.a.com/some/other/page`, are being successfully crawled by the FB debugger.

The problem with the FB debugger appears when using the built-in Angular server in DEV environment, so `https://dev.a.com:4202/some/other/page` can't be crawled correctly. I get a *URL returned a bad HTTP response code* kind of error, with `404` HTTP code. And when I click on *See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL*, I get:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Error</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <pre>Cannot GET /some/other/page</pre>
   </body>
</html>
```

The `404` code makes no sense to me. As I mentioned earlier, `https://dev.a.com:4202/some/other/page` works in my phone using a 4G connection, having the WiFi connection disabled.

Even more surprising, crawling `https://dev.a.com:4202` seem to work, but only if I adjust the content of the `og:url` meta-tag to be `https://dev.a.com:4202` as well.

The configuration for the Angular built in server is:

```
...

"serve": {
   "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
   "options": {
      "browserTarget": "frontend:build",
      "port": 4202,
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "ssl": true,
      "sslCert": "ssl/fullchain.pem",
      "sslKey": "ssl/privkey.pem",
      "disableHostCheck": true
   },
   "configurations": {
      "production": {
         "browserTarget": "frontend:build:production"
      },
      "dev": {
         "browserTarget": "frontend:build:dev"
      }
   }
}
...
```

My `/etc/hosts` file looks like:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1       localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

127.0.0.1 dev.a.com
```

So, what I am really asking for is, what would be the reason as to why the FB debugger returns `404` in these specific circumnstances when using the Angular built-in server?

Comment: _"when using the built-in Angular server in DEV environment, so `https://a.com:4202/some/other/page` can't be crawled correctly"_ - I thought your dev environment was `dev.a.com`?

Comment: _"crawling `https://dev.a.com:4202` seem to work, but only if I adjust the content of the og:url meta-tag to be `https://dev.a.com:4202` as well"_ - you had it pointing to something else before, or just not set at all? `og:url` must be set to the actual URL you want Facebook to fetch the meta data from.

Comment: @CBroe, apologies for the mistake. I had it corrected. Thanks

Comment: @CBroe, the `og:url` was pointing to `https://dev.a.com:4202/some/other/page`. In `PROD` environment would have been pointing to `https://a.com/some/other/page`. The only way that the crawler wouldn't give me an error in `DEV` was to change `og:url` to `https://dev.a.com:4202`, and to make it crawl that same URL, but that is not what I wanted to achieve.